# why do the backslashes specified in a path defined as a macro value get removed? Is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, environment-variables

In my Visual Studio application, I define a preprocessor macro SDK_INC in the project properties under C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions.

The macro is defined like so:

```
SDK_INC=$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)
```

Then in my code, I access the SDK include path like so:

```
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x

#define STR_VALUE(x) STRINGIZE(x)

char sdkPath[1000] = STR_VALUE(SDK_INC);
```

But, while debugging, I find out that the path fetched from the macro has all the backslashes removed.
I found the problem is not specific to $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) per se but it is a generic problem with anything having backslashes in it.
ie even if I define the macro directly without using $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) like so:

```
SDK_INC=C:\Program Files...blahblah
```

The path obtained at run-time will still have the backslashes removed.

Any insight on why it behaves this way and what should be done to get the path without any backslashes removed?

Comment: @Ron Why do you think meta programming should be avoided?

Comment: isn't it removed because it is recognize as (unknown) escape sequence?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Excerpt from "Effective C++", chapter 1, item 2, page 16: "_Macros like this (functions) have so many drawbacks, just thinking about them is painful._" I second that.

Comment: @Ron do you also refers to template meta programming?

Comment: @appleapple Macros only.

Comment: @Ron Did you read my comment at all? There is nothing about macros there. You said *"Avoid macros **and meta programming**"*. I would like to know what rationale do you have for avoiding meta programming.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek My English is to blame. What I meant to say was: avoid (function like) macros in C++.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a string containing backslashes will be processed for [Escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), i.e. the compiler looks for backslashes `\` followed by a known character.

This means a path like `C:\Program Files\Windows\blahblah` will see `\P`, `\W` and `\b`.

`P` and `W` are not defined in the list of recognized escape sequences and are replaced with the characters itself, `\P` gives `P`, same for `\W`.

`\b` however is defined as a backspace, and now you get

```
C:Program FilesWindows<backspace>lahblah
```

If you want to retain the backslashes, you must double them, e.g.

```
C:\\Program Files\\Windows\\blahblah
```

Now the compiler sees `\\` and replaces each with a single `\`.

Comment: dietche
Thanks for the useful info...
The path C:\Program Files... I gave was just an example to show the generic problem. As I explained in the question, my problem is to substitute the Platform SDK include path variable's value in the source code at run-time using the VS environment variable $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath). So, I have no control over replacing the single backslashes in this path with double backslashes. Can you suggest what I can do to extract the path "including" the backslashes out of $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)?

Comment: @AnuragSSharma There are raw string literals in C++11, but this will not work with macros, AFAIK.